# A simple Java loop does not work as intended

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

In Java, each number is associated with a character. For example:

```java
int ch = 65;
System.out.print((char)(ch)); // output: A
```

Similarly,

```java
System.out.print((char)(66)); // output: B
```

and so on

This is my code:

```java
for (int line = 1; line <= 4; line++) {
    for (int ch = 65; ch <= line; ch++) {
        System.out.print((char)(ch));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I was expecting this output:

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
```

Instead, I got:

(yup, nothing!)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the loop condition of your inner `for` loop - the loop will run _until_ `ch <= line` - do you see what might be the issue?

Comment: ch<=line       is always false

Comment: You have condition that 4 should be less than line and then condition that this line should be higher than 65

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your condition `ch <= line` is always false.

To fix it and get the expected result you can change the conditions and the loop limits:

```java
int startingChar = 65;
for (int line = 0; line < 4; line++) {
    int ch;
    for (ch = startingChar ; ch <= startingChar + line; ch++) {
        System.out.print((char)(ch));
    }
    startingChar = ch;
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: There's an error in the increment of your inner loop. If I try it like this a lot of garbage is printed.

Comment: @RobSpoor is that better now ?

Comment: It's still the same. `ch` and `startingChar` are incremented together. That means that `ch <= startingChar + line` will always be true until `startingChar + line` overflows. I tried it by replacing `startingChar` with `ch` and the following inner loop: `for (int col = 0; col <= line; col++, ch++)`

Comment: That last update fixes the issue.

Comment: Yep, i see my mistake. That's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop, `ch` starts at 65 and has to be smaller than or equal to `line` from the outer loop. But `line` from the outer loop goes from `1` to `4` - none of these four values is bigger than or equal to `65` (the smallest possible value for `ch`)

This is the reason why your inner loop is never entered.

You could try to do a "desk test" by writing down the values of your variables on a piece of paper and play that you are the computer and execute all the steps manually.